# PN532 sometimes not responding with ESP32

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, pn532

Im using ESP32 with PN532 NFC module with I2C
And Im using this library https://github.com/elechouse/PN532
And using this documents https://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/PN532_module_V3/PN532_%20Manual_V3.pdf

Normally, it finds the PN532 and reads the card successfully when I scan it. However, sometimes after starting, it doesn't detect the PN532 and never finds it.It say PN53x card not found!. When I unplug and plug in the sensor cable, the ESP32 can detect the sensor, but I shouldn't have to do it this way. Therefore, if it can't find the PN532 twice, I wanted to reset it as follows:

```
void resetPN532() {
digitalWrite(PNP532_IRQ_Pin, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(PNP532_IRQ_Pin, HIGH);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(PNP532_RSTO_Pin, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(PNP532_RSTO_Pin, HIGH);
 }
```

This is code for the find:

```
`  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  processCommand("command");
  }

  if (!versiondata) {
    Serial.println("PN53x card not found!");
    resetCounter++;
    if (resetCounter >= 2) {
      Serial.println("Reset PNP");
      resetPN532();
      resetCounter = 0;
    }


    return false;
  }

`
```

This is my connections:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXwmk.png)

Why I faced with this issue I dont know but how can I solve this problem ?

. When I unplug and plug in the sensor cable, the ESP32 can detect the sensor, but I shouldn't have to do it this way. Therefore, if it can't find the PN532 twice, I wanted to reset it as follows:

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem too, I checked the current source and found that the voltage source is not able to provide enough current to keep the circuit working, so the problem was solved by replacing a voltage source with a higher current. the necessary current for ESP32 is at least 500mA and i think 500mA for pn532 is enough so use at least a 1A power source